# Rendering redirect component based on ajax request

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4

I've got a home route '/' and whenever a user goes to that route I want to send him either to his page if he is authenticated or send him to '/login' route if he isn't authenticated. In order to send a user to his page I make a request to the server, fetch his id and redirect him to the route based on the id I get from the server. However I'm a bit confused as to how to implement that logic in my Home component correctly. What would be the best way to render redirect component based on the result of the ajax request?

```
class Home extends React.Component {

    async componentDidMount() {
        const response = await Api.getUserId();
        const id = response.data._id;
    }  

    render() {
        if(this.props.userStatus.authenticated) {
            return <Redirect to={{
                pathname: `/${id}`,
                state: { from: this.props.location }
            }}/>
        }
        return <Redirect to={{
            pathname: '/login',
            state: { from: this.props.location }
        }}/>
    }
}

export default connectComponent(['userStatus'], Home);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:
Create a new component called PrivateRoute:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Redirect, withRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { isLogin } from '../actions/actions_rents'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    return(
        <Route {...rest} render={props => (
        isAuthenticated ? (
        <Component />
        ) : (
        <Redirect to={{
          pathname: '/login',
          state: { from: props.location }
        }}/>
      )
    )}/>
  )
}
```

And then in you App.js or where you have your routes, you call PrivateRoute and pass as props the component Home in this case:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
  <PrivateRoute path="/" component={IndexRents} />
</Switch>
```

Also, I recommend you see this example:
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I have a problem with. The idea of Home component is that it redirects authenticated users to their respective pages by the ids that I retrieve from the server. What i want to happen: a user goes to '/' => if he is authenticated I fetch his id from the server(by providing a token), then redirect him to his personal page. What I'm confused about is how to implement the "fetch user's id, then redirect based on the id you fetched" asynchronous logic. The route to which I want to redirect a user is based on the result I get from the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
 fetch('//offline-news-api.herokuapp.com/stories')
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    const login = response.ok;
    class Entry extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        }
        render() {
            return (
                <Router>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
                        <Route path="/" render={() => (
                          login ? (
                              <Common/>
                          ) : (
                            <Redirect to="/login"/>
                          )
                        )}/>
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            );
        }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<Entry/>, document.getElementById('root'));

})
.then(function (stories) {
});
```

Comment: you can define class after asynchronous had a result.